# FastAPI python PUT request

Tags: python, reactjs, fastapi

im trying to run a put request but i keep getting error type object 'User' has no attribute 'first_name' when i have declared first_name in the schema. this is my code for the api request which calls the function update_user from services.

main.py:

```
@app.put("/api/userUpdate/{id}", status_code=200)
async def update_User(
    id = int,
    user = _schemas.User,
    db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_db),
):
    await _services.update_user(id, user, db)
    return {"message", "Successfully Updated"}
```

services.py:

```
async def get_user_by_id(id: int, db: _orm.Session):
    return db.query(_models.User).filter(_models.User.id == id).first()

async def update_user(id: int, user: _schemas.User, db: _orm.Session):
    user_db = await get_user_by_id(id, db)

    user_db.first_name = user.first_name
    user_db.last_name = user.last_name
    user_db.email = user.email

    db.commit()
    db.refresh(user_db)

    return _schemas.User.from_orm(user_db)
```

schemas.py

```
class _UserBase(_pydantic.BaseModel):
    email: str
    
    
class UserCreate(_UserBase):
    hashed_password: str
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    user_role : str
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class User(_UserBase):
    id: int
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    user_role : str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

models.py

```
class User(_database.Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = _sql.Column(_sql.Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = _sql.Column(_sql.String, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = _sql.Column(_sql.String)
    first_name = _sql.Column(_sql.String, index=True)
    last_name = _sql.Column(_sql.String, index=True)
    user_role = _sql.Column(_sql.String, index = True)
    
    leads = _orm.relationship("Lead", back_populates="owner")

    def verify_password(self, password: str):
        return _hash.bcrypt.verify(password, self.hashed_password)
```

request from frontend:

```
const handleUpdateUser = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        first_name: userName,
        last_name: userSurname,
        email: userEmail,
      }),
    };
    const response = await fetch(`/api/userUpdate/${id}`, requestOptions);
    if (!response.ok) {
      setErrorMessage("Something went wrong when updating lead");
    } else {
      cleanFormData();
      handleModal();
    }
  };
```

when running the request i get the error

`AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'first_name'`

Comment: The function definition for `update_User()` seems very odd.  What is the point of `id = int`?  int is a _type_.  I think maybe you meant to have `id: int`?  What is the point of `user = _schemas.User`?  This assigns user to the `User` class object.  Did you intend to use the `id` value to look up the `user` object?

Comment: Yeah i wanted to use the id to look up the user object to then update the specific user data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong is hinted at in the error message. If you read it carefully, it says "AttributeError: **type object** 'User' has no attribute 'first_name'". This means somewhere, you're assigning a variable into the type of User instead of an instance of the User class.

And I believe the place where that happened is in the main file where you had `user = _schemas.User`. This sets the default value of `user` to be the type of `_schemas.User`. I believe you are trying to type hint that `user` is going to be of type `_shcmas.User`. If that's the case you should use colon instead of equals like so: `user: _schemas.User`. You also set `id = int` instead of `id: int`. Everything should work after you fix those two type hint mishaps.

```
@app.put("/api/userUpdate/{id}", status_code=200)
async def update_User(
    id: int,
    user: _schemas.User,
    db: _orm.Session = _fastapi.Depends(_services.get_db),
):
    await _services.update_user(id, user, db)
    return {"message", "Successfully Updated"}
```

Comment: `{id}` is a component of the url, so I can see how it is an argument to this function.  But where is `user` supposed to come from?

Comment: @JohnGordon user will come from the request body. It is not required to specify so in FastAPI if the body is optional but if it is required you can do `from fastapi import Body` and then `user: _schemas.User = Body(...)`

Comment: thank you - the post function is working perfectly!